# Error: invalid address in solidity constructor

Tags: solidity, constructor

I get a huge error message (~1MB) starting with

```
Error: invalid address (arg="_readAccess", coderType="address", value={"constructor":{"contractName":"SenderAccess","abi":[...
```

when executing a test written in TypeScript:

```
it("should be possible to create such an option", async () => {
    const accessControl = await SenderAccess.new(); // OK
    const validator = await NumberRangeValidation.new(1, 5); // OK
    // This will crash
    const option = await NumberConfigOptionDefinition.new('foo.bar.baz', accessControl, accessControl, validator);
});
```

The contract looks like this:

```
contract NumberConfigOptionDefinition is ConfigOptionDefinition {
    NumberValidation public validator;

    constructor(string memory _name, AccessControl _readAccess, AccessControl _writeAccess, NumberValidation _validator)
        ConfigOptionDefinition(_name, _readAccess, _writeAccess) public {
        validator = _validator;
    }
}

contract ConfigOptionDefinition {
    ... fields ...

    constructor(string memory _name, AccessControl _readAccess, AccessControl _writeAccess) internal {
        name = _name;
        readAccess = _readAccess;
        writeAccess = _writeAccess;
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you console log the content of the `accessControl` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
const option = await NumberConfigOptionDefinition.new(
    'foo.bar.baz',
    accessControl,
    accessControl,
    validator
);
```

To this:

```
const option = await NumberConfigOptionDefinition.new(
    'foo.bar.baz',
    accessControl.address,
    accessControl.address,
    validator.address
);
```

Comment: Now it starts to make sense: The huge dump is actually the JavaScript representation of the contract object! Thanks.